# How to use "american" language for babel in latex export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have a question about the `babel` latex package (not `org-babel`, which allows source code in documents).

I need to load the babel package with the `american` language set so I added:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[american]{babel}
```

to my org file. However, in the tex export it adds `english` to this so that the tex output has:

```
\usepackage[american, english]{babel}
```

which I don't want. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, if you include the `babel` package with the brackets for package options, the org exporter adds as the value of the current language as an option for the package.  So you can just set the `LANGUAGE` option as in

```
#+LANGUAGE: en-us
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[]{babel}
```

or

```
#+LANGUAGE: en-us
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[american]{babel}
```

The mapping between LANGUAGE code and babel option is given in variable `org-latex-babel-language-alist`.